# How to get the number of columns with ONLY NA values?

Tags: r

How to get the number of columns with ALL `NA` values? Meaning that every value in a column needs to be `NA`, for the column to be counted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `colSums` to count NA in the column and check if is the same as all row numbers of the dataframe. Here is a reproducible example where there are 2 columns with all values NA:

```r
sum(colSums(is.na(df)) == nrow(df))
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(NA, NA, NA), V2 = c(1, 2, NA), V3 = c(NA, NA, NA), V4 = c(2, 2, 1))

df
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4
#> 1 NA  1 NA  2
#> 2 NA  2 NA  2
#> 3 NA NA NA  1
```